# Build cluster array only produce 1 element

Tags: arrays, cluster-computing, labview, nidaqmx, data-acquisition

I've been trying to make an array of clusters in LabVIEW, I know I can make it in the front panel but I need to make it from the block diagram because I want to input something into my array of clusters and to make my program function correctly I need an array of the cluster with 3 elements, so I add 3 elements into build cluster array function but it turned out it only produces 1 element, so can someone tell where is my error? Thanks for reading and please help me if you know how to fix it.

This is photo of my block diagram :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try building your cluster using a "bundle" node and then feeding that output to a "build array" node.
This will do the trick.

[image: How to build an array of cluster]

The usage of the "build cluster array" is slightly different with respect to what you need to do.